# Gitlab Runner taking Too long to run the pipeline

Tags: gitlab, yaml, runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I had created a specific runner for my gitlab project,
its taking too long to run the pipeline.
Its is getting stuck in Cypress test mainly.
After "All Specs passed" it will not move forward.

```
- build
- test
build:
stage: build
image: gradle:jdk11
script:
 - gradle --no-daemon build
artifacts:
 paths:
   - build/distributions
 expire_in: 1 day
 when: always

junit-test:
stage: test
image: gradle:jdk11
dependencies: []
script:
 - gradle test
timeout: 5m

cypress-test:
stage: test
image: registry.gitlab.com/sahajsoft/gurukul2022/csv-parser-srijan:latestSrigin2
dependencies:
 - build
script:
 - unzip -q build/distributions/csv-parser-srijan-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip -d build/distributions
 - sh build/distributions/csv-parser-srijan-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/csv-parser-srijan &
 - npm install --save-dev cypress-file-upload 
 - npx cypress run --browser chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

A recommended approach is to try and replicate your script (from your pipeline) locally, from your computer.

It will allow to check:

- how long those commands take
- if there is any interactive step, where a command might expect a user entry, and wait for stdin.

The second point would explain why, in an unattended environment like a pipeline one, "it will not move forward".

Comment: i tried to run everything locally as you said but locally everything is working fine
but on pipeline cypress get stuck

Comment: @UtkarshSingh Strange. Is there a cypress verbose more or logs you could monitor while the pipeline is executing?